# How to double integrate a function in R

Tags: r, integration, auc

I am trying to use the following code to calculate the integrate and double integrate. I used the trapz to perform integration with respect to time and  find area under the curve (AUC_C and AUC_fvfree).

Now I want to calculate AUC which should be calculated as AUC = ∬fv$C*fv_free with respect to time for each variable. So. it may be written as :
AUC = ∫fv$C dt * ∫fv_free dt .

I was thinking of maybe applying a code that calculates partial AUCs at each time point to calculate each integral term in AUC separately and then adding them up. However, I could not find any specific command/code that will calculate partial AUC at each time point. Is there a way to work around this?
Any inputs will be helpful.

Thanks

```
library (deSolve)
library(rootSolve)
library(pracma)

ka = 0.1; CL = 0.2; Ke = 0.3; R = 10; KD = 0.1

LV <- function(time,state, params) {
  C <- state[1]
  P <- state[2]
  fun_sp <- function(p){p + ((C/R)*p/(p+(KD/R))) -1}
  p <<- uniroot.all(fun_sp, c(0,1))
  fb <- p/(p+(KD/R))
  dC <- fb*ka*C - CL*C + P*CL - Ke*C
  dP <- CL*C - P*CL 
  list(c(dC, dP), free = fb)
}

state_ini = c(C=100,P=0)
time = c(seq(1, 24 , 1))

fv <- ode(state_ini, time, LV, parms, 
          method = "lsoda", rtol=1e-6, atol=1e-6, 
          verbose=FALSE)
fv <- as.data.frame(fv)
fv_free <- fv$free

## integration of fv$C w.r.t. time
AUC_C <- trapz(time, fv$C)    

## integration of fv_free w.r.t. time
AUC_fvfree <- trapz(time, fv_free)   

AUC <- ???
```